# Highlighting feature by Longitude and Latitude in OpenLayers

Tags: qgis, openlayers

I used Qgis2Web and I'm really a beginner. Is there a way can I highlight a feature using their coordinates?
I'm currently developing a website which suggests location based from pre-defined inputs. And the only thing i have is the lat and lon. I hope these helps :)

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail? Do you mean have users type in long/lat into a field, and features at that location on the map are highlighted? Or do you mean you want to specify the long/lat in your map code?

Comment: I'm currently developing a website which suggests a location based from the pre-defined inputs. And the only thing i have is the lat and lon. I hope these helps :)

Answer (score 1):

qgis2web exports all layers as geoJson so you have all your features available. You could use [map.forEachFeatureAtPixel](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel) method passing your coordinates as the *pixel* parameter. The hard part so is to modify the javascript files exportet by qgis2web.

So actually I would recommand to use QGIS server and load the layers as WMS or WFS layers:

1. On WMS layers you can access and highlight the features with [getGetFeatureInfoUrl](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html#getGetFeatureInfoUrl) passing your coordinates as a parameter. [This example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html) may give you some hints.
2. On WFS layers you can access and highlight the features with [forEachFeatureAtPixel](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel) passing your coordinates as the *pixel* parameter. [This example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html) may give you some hints.